# How do I make a domain name transfer without dealing with an agent

Tags: domains, business

I have been talking with a domain name holder, and he has agreed to sell me one of his domains. He said he will transfer the domain to my name with godaddy (I will register for an account with godaddy first). How should I process the payment so that neither party (me or him) is at risk of fraud? TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use godaddy freely to do the transfer.
How ever to receive and give payments you can use escrow.com to prevent fraud.
https://www.escrow.com/index.asp

good luck.

Comment: Thanks, the payment method was what I was concerned about. Now I am wondering if Escrow.com is the industry standard, or is it one of many companies that provide this type of service?

Comment: It kind of is the Standard. Lots of sites use/recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy has an internal facility to "push" domains to other accounts. Its there in the domain manager (and free of cost).